# How python ConfigParser module translate the string "\r\n" to CRLF?

Tags: python

The testing code:

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('test_config.ini')

orig_str = """line1\r\nline2"""
config_str = config.get('General', 'orig_str')
print orig_str == config_str
```

and the content of test_config.ini is:

```
[General]
orig_str = line1\r\nline2
```

What I want is the config_str can be the same value as the orig_str.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write multiline configuration values, you just need to prepend a space at the beginning of the following lines. For example:

```
[General]
orig_str = line1
 line2
```

returns `'line1\nline2'` in my OS (Linux), but maybe in a different OS might return the `'\r'` as well. Otherwise, it would be easy to replace `'\n'` with `'\r\n'` as you need.

I'd say that whatever library you're using to encode the message should take care of the replacement. Anyway, if that's not the case, you can create your own `ConfigParser` as follows:

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

class MyConfigParser(ConfigParser):
    def get(self, section, option):
      return ConfigParser.get(self, section, option).replace('\n', '\r\n')

config = MyConfigParser()
config.read('test_config.ini')

orig_str = """line1\r\nline2"""
config_str = config.get('General', 'orig_str')
print orig_str == config_str    # Prints True
```

Comment: thanks, but what I need is '\r\n', because this string is a HTTP request.

Comment: @pvd If you really need to do that, I've added an example in which a `ConfigParser` subclass implements the desired functionality.